# Cannot connect to AWS lightsail mysql using HeidiSQL with SSH

Tags: ssh, mysql, putty, amazon-web-services

I need to connect to AWS lightsail mysql instance using HeidiSQL with SSH.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.enovision.net/mysql-ssh-tunnel-heidisql/)

But it doesn't allow me to connect.

It shows

> Plink exited unexpected

I have added private key file as which was generated from Puttygen.

Did anyone encounter this and how did they fix it, please?

Comment: Finally could able to find the solution. Tried with MySQL workbench and i could connect to the server.

Comment: hi @codecanyon, would you mind put the answer , please?